# How to export all compilation errors and warnings from VSCode Problems view to txt/excel or similar?

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-studio-code, export

Is there any opportunity to export all compilation errors and warnings from Problems view of VSCode to some tabular format?

If the number of errors is quite big, it's useful to analyse them somewhere, outside of VSCode.

Comment: have you found anything?

Answer (score 2):

This still isn't possible in vscode without an extension.  So I published one:

[Problems: Copy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.problems-copy)

You can copy all the problems in the workspace or for the current file.  And these can be filtered to include/exclude `Errors/Warnings/Informations/Hints`.

Sample keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+c",        // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "problems-copy.copyAll",
  "args": {
    "errors": true,     // will be included in the result
    "warnings": true

    // any category not in the keybinding will be excluded from the result
    // "hints": true
    // "informations": true
  }
}
```

The output is added to the clipboard.  Sample output:

```
[
    {
        "resource": "/c:/Users/Mark/folder-operations/extension.js",
        "code": {
            "value": "no-unused-vars",
            "target": {
                "$mid": 1,
                "path": "/docs/rules/no-unused-vars",
                "scheme": "https",
                "authority": "eslint.org"
            }
        },
        "severity": 1,
        "message": "'args' is defined but never used.",
        "source": "eslint",
        "startLineNumber": 32,
        "startColumn": 102,
        "endLineNumber": 32,
        "endColumn": 106
    }
]
```

I have plans to produce simpler output, including a csv version.  What fields would you want in a csv or simple output?

Answer (score 2):

While not as easy than an export, VSCode 1.62 (Oct. 2021) does announce:

> ### [Copy multiple problems](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25290#issuecomment-949472297)
>
> You can now select and copy multiple problems in Problems view.

By selecting all the problems you need, you can now copy them in one operation, without having to install any plugin.

See [issue 25290](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25290#issuecomment-949472297) and [commit ae8175e](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/ae8175ebfe075b5e95b65924dae8db4383c6a47c)

> You can now select multiple problems and copy them:
>
> [image: select multiple prbs]
>
> You can also select the file/resource and copy all problems in that file:
>
> [image: select file]
>
> You can also copy all problem using the context menu in the empty area:
>
> [image: copy from context menu]

Comment: Anchor Link does not exists

Comment: @devfric Thank you for this feedback. I have restored the link and added some illustrations.